# Convert decimal minutes into Minutes:Seconds?

Tags: sql, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Anyone know if there's a function to convert decimal minutes into Minutes:Seconds in
Snowflake?

For example:

```
input: 8.5 (as in 8.5 minutes) 
output: 8:30 (as in 8 minutes 30 seconds)
```

Source: https://twitter.com/jasongrahn/status/1420768503133401095

Comment: Nice puzzle, the ideal solution would be `'00:00:00'::TIME + INTERVAL '<decimal> time_part'`

Comment: I didn't think of TIMEADD! Thanks for adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the two excellent solutions already provided together:

```
SELECT TIME_FROM_PARTS(0,0,8.5*60)
```

This is nice because it's straight SQL - [UDF's may not perform as quick](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html)

[TIME_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_from_parts.html) allows you to pass not just seconds but also minutes,nanoseconds etc.

[image]

If you go over 1 day just switch to [TIMESTAMP_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/timestamp_from_parts.html)

Below I pass in 5.1 million nanoseconds returning 1 month, 28 days and 40 minutes.  This demonstrates the extendibility of the built in functions that can always be used elegantly.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense! I over-complicated separating minutes, when *60 would have been enough the whole time

Comment: Yes ... instead of coming in with pre-determined ways of solving a problem ... let the functions take the centre stage ... we just have to treat data like food.  The less it's touched the better. So when we design tables - make sure the table  seamlessly works with as many functions as possible. Plus hindsight helps ... seeing the other 2 excellent solutions helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using **[TIMEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/timeadd.html)** to add number of seconds since midnight:

```
SELECT TIMEADD(second, 8.5 * 60, '00:00'::TIME) AS res;
                       --arg
```

Output:

```
RES
00:08:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build a date from parts, and separate the decimals from the integer minutes.
You can create a SQL UDF for convenience:

```sql
create function from_decimal_minutes(minutes float)
returns time
as $$
    time_from_parts(0, floor(minutes), 60*(minutes-floor(minutes)))
$$
;

select from_decimal_minutes(8.5);
-- 00:08:30
;
```